# object tag reloads when css display none to block

Tags: javascript, events, object, svg, load

I have an html page with an object tag containing an svg object.  The svg object reloads every time the display on the containing div changes from none to block.  This is causing a load event to get generated   for the svg object.  This happens in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Is this a bug in Chrome, or is this correct behavior?  I know browsers will sometimes defer load until an element is visible, but I didn't think they should reload every time the display changes.  I know I could use visibility=hidden but this is part of a large, legacy library that has many styling dependencies and so it is not so easy to change.

Here is a minimal code snippet that demonstrates the problem (on chrome).  I am using chrome 39 on Windows 7.

```
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var toggle = 0;
        $('#button').on('click', function () {
            if (toggle % 2 == 0) {
                $('#www').css('display', 'none');
            } else {
                $('#www').css('display', 'block');
            }
            toggle++;
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="www">
<object id="ggggg" name="ggggg" type="image/svg+xml" data="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/NewTux.svg" width="583" height="471">    </object>
</div>
<input type="button" value="abcd" id="button"/>
</body>
```

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=27480. One possible workaround is to use an <iframe> instead of <object>.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's a bug or not.  I don't think that CSS defines what a browser should do with cached assets when display is set to none.  One of the browser devs on here may know.

However, there are alternatives you could try:

1. Move the object off the page, eg. (position: absolute; left: -9999px;}
2. Collapse the object, eg. {width: 0; height: 0}